# erro Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

ao clicar numa aba em meu projeto é retornado o erro: 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function.

Código:

```
function menu() {
    $('.nav-toggle').live('click', function() {
        if($(".nav-aberta").hasClass("side-fechado")) {
            $('.nav-aberta').animate({
                left: "0px",
            }, 100, function() {
                $(".nav-aberta").removeClass("side-fechado");
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.nav-aberta').animate({
                left: "-250px",
            }, 100, function() {
                $(".nav-aberta").addClass("side-fechado");
            });
        }
    });     
}
```

function refazer(){
    var tamanhoJanela = $(window).width();
    // $('.nav-toggle').hide();

```
if (tamanhoJanela < 800) { 
    $('.nav-aberta').css('left', '-250px').addClass('side-fechado');
    $('.nav-toggle').css('display', 'initial');
} else {
    $('.nav-aberta').css('left', '0px').addClass('side-fechado');
}   
menu();
```

}

```
//Menu Sidebar
$(window).resize(function() {
    refazer();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    refazer();
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
    refazer();
});
```

Alguem sabe me dizer o que pode ser? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Jquery tá adicionado certinho?

Comment: Você deve ter atualizado a versão do jQuery que esse código usa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

verifique a versão do seu jquery, pois o `.live` foi descontinuado na versão 1.7 e removido da versão 1.9 em diante.

Fonte: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Sugestão: se sua versão for 1.7 ou superior, vc pode utilizar o .on() como alternativa, exemplo:

```
$('.nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    if($(".nav-aberta").hasClass("side-fechado")) {
        $('.nav-aberta').animate({
            left: "0px",
        }, 100, function() {
            $(".nav-aberta").removeClass("side-fechado");
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.nav-aberta').animate({
            left: "-250px",
        }, 100, function() {
            $(".nav-aberta").addClass("side-fechado");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Valeu deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. abraços

Answer (score 0):

O uso de `$('.nav-toggle').on('click', function() {` **não é equivalente** ao uso de `$('.nav-toggle').live('click', function() {` da API antiga.

Ou seja o `.live` indentificava quando o DOM era modificado a aplicava os eventos novamente, tanto que o próprio link http://api.jquery.com/live/ que a outra resposta aponta exatamente como deve ser feito:

```
$( >>>>SELECTOR<<< ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( >>>>SELECTOR<<<, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, >>>>SELECTOR<<<, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Ou seja se usa a versão 1.4.3 até a 1.6 deveria usar assim:

```
function menu() {
    $(document).delegate('.nav-toggle', 'click', function() {
        if($(".nav-aberta").hasClass("side-fechado")) {
            $('.nav-aberta').animate({
                left: "0px",
            }, 100, function() {
                $(".nav-aberta").removeClass("side-fechado");
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.nav-aberta').animate({
                left: "-250px",
            }, 100, function() {
                $(".nav-aberta").addClass("side-fechado");
            });
        }
    });     
}
```

Agora usando nas versões 1.7 até a atual (versão 3) deve usar o `.on`, assim:

```
function menu() {
    $(document).on('.nav-toggle', 'click', function() {
        if($(".nav-aberta").hasClass("side-fechado")) {
            $('.nav-aberta').animate({
                left: "0px",
            }, 100, function() {
                $(".nav-aberta").removeClass("side-fechado");
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.nav-aberta').animate({
                left: "-250px",
            }, 100, function() {
                $(".nav-aberta").addClass("side-fechado");
            });
        }
    });     
}
```